# Bootstrap 4 Grid Issues not aligning the way I need it to

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a list of cards that display data from my database. I have tried to redo my code over and over but I am not able to find the right way. May I also note that I am new to Bootstrap and coding.

My current Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


                <?php
            require 'connect.php';
            $query = "SELECT * FROM communities";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            $check_communities = mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0;

            if($check_communities)
            {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
              {
                ?>
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> <?php echo $row['name']; ?></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
            <?php
          }
        }
        else
        {
          echo "TEST";
        }
        ?>
```

The way I want to have it is like this.

[image]

I am getting this:

[image]

Comment: Post your rendered HTML please, not the PHP

Comment: can you please share the <head> tag? I think you forgot about some meta tags

Comment: @j08691 This is my only code that I have.

Comment: @Giuppox This is my only code.

Comment: oh! i suggest you to divide everything in tags. I'll do an answer to show u how

Comment: You posted your PHP code. We need the HTML that gets generated.

Comment: @j08691 the PHP in this case is actually the problem - with the `while` loop.

Comment: you are creating a row every loop

Comment: @disinfor I. still. would. like. to. see. the. rendered. HTML. please

Comment: @j08691 I don't disagree with that, and normally I would also ask for that as well.

Comment: @DevinHenrickson to get the rendered HTML, view source on your page and copy what is actually output to the browser - just that loop section, not the whole page. That's what j08691 is asking for.

Comment: view-source:http://testingsite1.devinhenrickson.com/test

Comment: The most obvious problem is that you are opening 5 divs and only closing 4 of them. That's why the cards are not only beneath each other but also indented in each row

Comment: Closed them and now I get a new issues. Now one at the top is spaced to the right then the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is every time you run your loop, you are also including the row. You need to move the `container` and `row` out of the loop:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<?php
require 'connect.php';
$query             = "SELECT * FROM communities";
$query_run         = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );
$check_communities = mysqli_num_rows( $query_run ) > 0;
?>
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        if ( $check_communities )
        {
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query_run ) )
        {
        ?>

        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> <?php echo $row[ 'name' ]; ?></h5>
                </div><!-- /card-body -->
            </div><!-- /card -->
        </div><!-- /col-auto -->

            <?php
            }
            }
            else {
                echo "TEST";
            }
            ?>

        </div><!-- /row -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
```

Comment: You solved my issue. I had to close my last DIV. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I cleaned it up a bit to include closing div comments to make sure all tags were accounted for.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a row in each while iteration
fixe the container and row before generating cards so they will align in one row

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">

                <?php
            require 'connect.php';
            $query = "SELECT * FROM communities";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            $check_communities = mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0;

            if($check_communities)
            {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
              {
                ?>

        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> <?php echo $row['name']; ?></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <?php
          }
        }
        else
        {
          echo "TEST";
        }
        ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted because we have the same answer and did so within seconds of each other.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can use bootstrap columns and loop only the column not the container and row..

```html
  

<?php
            require 'connect.php';
            $query = "SELECT * FROM communities";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            $check_communities = mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0;

            if($check_communities)
            {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
              {
                ?>
    <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"> <?php echo $row[ 'name' ]; ?></h5>
            </div>
    </div>
    <?php
          }
        }
        else
        {
          echo "TEST";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all the answers given above. The problem is you are generating a new row for every new item in a loop, so you **are** getting everything in a new row.

I have a different solution to it altogether. If your elements are gonna be adapting to the number of database elements, which can be a lot, you can use **flex** as a cure.
Using columns is a good way. Flex is an alternative approach and **Bootstrap 4** has fantastic **flex classes**, like `d-flex`, `flex-row`, etc. and `flex-wrap` to **wrap** your rows too!

Read about it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

Comment: `row` by default in BS4 is a flex element. OP is already using flex.

Comment: @disinfor Oh. I was unaware of that. Thanks for letting me know!